# code coverage for angularJS service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a controller that is calling a service. I want to write my unit tests such that I get coverage on the success and error functions of the then function.

```
maApp.controller('editEmailAndPasswordController', 
                 ["$scope", "emailAndPasswordService",
    function editEmailAndPasswordController($scope, emailAndPasswordService) {
        $scope.EmailId = 'as@as.com';
        $scope.CurrentPassword = '';
        $scope.Success = false;

        $scope.save = function () {
            var request = {
                currentPassword: $scope.CurrentPassword,
                newEmailId: $scope.EmailId
            };
            emailAndPasswordService.save(request).then(function (data) {
                $scope.Success = true;
            }, function (data, status, header, config) {
                $scope.Success = false;
            });
        };
    }]);
```

This is what I have got so for. I want another test for the fail condition as well, but not sure how to set up the mock service.

```
describe('Controllers', function () {
    var $scope, ctrl, controller, svc, def;
    describe('editEmailAndPasswordController', function () {

        beforeEach(function() {
            module('maApp');
        });

        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $q) {
            ctrl = $controller;
            svc = {
                save: function () {
                    def = $q.defer();
                    return def.promise;
                }
            };
            spyOn(svc, 'save').andCallThrough();
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = ctrl('editEmailAndPasswordController', { $scope: $scope, emailAndPasswordService: svc });
        }));

        it('should set ShowEdit as false upon save', function () {
            $scope.ShowEdit = true;
            $scope.EmailId = 'newEmail';
            $scope.CurrentPassword = 'asdf1';

            $scope.save();
            expect($scope.EmailId).toBe('as@as.com');
            expect($scope.Success).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some real problems with this code.

1. Don't call ".andCallThrough()"- that way your test depends on the implementaton of the service and means your controller is not isolated. The main idea is to create unit tests.

   `svc = {save: jasmine.createSpy()};`

   `svc.save.andReturn(...);`
2. You can't assert against `expect($scope.EmailId).toBe('as@as.com');` because you change the value in the code to `$scope.EmailId = 'newEmail';`
3. you can create 2 private methods for readability

   `function success(value) {
     var defer = q.defer();
     defer.resolve(value);
     return defer.promise;
   }`

   `function failure(value){
     var defer = q.defer();
     defer.reject(value);
     return defer.promise;
   }`

Thus in the first test you can call

`svc.save.andReturn(success());`

`$scope.$digest()`

`expect($scope.Success).toBeTruthy();`

And in the other test you will have the same but:

`svc.save.andReturn(failure());`

`$scope.$digest()`

`expect($scope.Success).toBeFalsy();`

Comment: In your success function you are calling reject, just changed that on my side and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Ah my mistake sorry , but you got the idea and glad that i helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

In one case, you want the promise to be successful, so you want to resolve the deferred:

```
$scope.save();

def.resolve('whatever');
$scope.$apply();

expect($scope.Success).toBe(true);
...
```

In the other case, you want the promise to be a failure, so uou want to reject the deferred:

```
$scope.save();

def.reject('whatever');
$scope.$apply();

expect($scope.Success).toBe(false);
...
```

This is explained in [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q).